# MVC5 reuse of partial views and jquery, without conflicting the DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, nested, partial-views

Is there any way (even not using partial views) I can better write this and not have to use the Dynamic Id's for my tags? I'm looking for a something newer than [the best answer until now, hopefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966850/mvc-3-reuse-of-partial-views-and-jquery-without-conflicting-the-dom)

```
public class Estates
{
    public List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Addresses
{
    ...
    ...
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
public class Phone
{
    id..
    num..
    active..
}
```

HTML

```
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Addresses.Count(); index++)
{
   @html.partial(....)
}
```

Partial View - herein lies my question

```
@*Needed to replace div with ajax return html data*@
@*Otherwise Jquery doesn't know what field to update as it is rendered multiple times with the same id*@
<div id=@modelId> 
...
```

ScriptFILE.js: *(secondquestion?) Where sadly at this point i'd be sending the id from the view to the .js file to run ...*

```
$("#"+@modelId.ToString()).click(function(){ ... call some ajax...  });
```

Comment: That question you linked is still current. Not much has changed.

Comment: No need to write the javascript in view at all... use a common class on those elements and one delegated event handler for all of them. No need for element ID's that way